# Cannot find module 'quasar/dist/babel-transforms/imports.js with VueJs and Quasar after upgrading quasarv1 to quasarv2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, quasar-framework, quasar

After upgrading quasar1.0.0 to quasarV2.

error  in ./src/main.ts

Syntax Error: Thread Loader (Worker 0)
Cannot find module 'quasar/dist/babel-transforms/imports.js'
Require stack:

I have also vue2, typescript.
How it can be solved?

package.json:

````
  "name": "clientapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --open",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build:watch": "vue-cli-service build --watch",
    "test": "jest --silent",
    "test:rebuild": "jest --silent --clearCache & vue-cli-service build & jest",
    "test:warn": "jest",
    "test:coverage": "jest  --silent --collect-coverage",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.0",
    "@quasar/app": "^3.2.6",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "core-js": "^3.20.2",
    "quasar": "^2.4.10",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "@types/vue-datetime": "^1.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "postcss-rtl": "^1.2.3",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-quasar": "~3.0.1",
    "vue-loader-v16": "^16.0.0-beta.5.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}```
````

Comment: Just showing your `package.json` file is not helpful. Did you attempt the upgrade while running your app? If that's the case, stop your app and re-`serve` it.

Comment: No, I did not update the running program. Maybe i need show u some other file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.